# LWJGL Multi texturing not working

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl, multitexturing

I'm currently learning some OpenGL and I want to have 2 different textures (diffuse and specular) applied to a cube. The problem is that only the first texture (of texture unit 0) is accessible; both samplers seem to use it, instead of using two different ones.

Even if i assign both sampler uniforms to 1, the first (diffuse texture) is used. I presume I must have overlooked something.

The relevant part of my `init()` looks like this:

```
texture = Texture.loadTextureFromFile("res/texture/stone_07_diffuse.jpg");
textureSpecular = Texture.loadTextureFromFile("res/texture/stone_07_specular.jpg");

shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram();
shaderProgram.attachVertexShader("res/shader/LightTest.vsh");
shaderProgram.attachFragmentShader("res/shader/LightTest.fsh");
shaderProgram.link()

ShaderProgram.bind(shaderProgram);
{
    shaderProgram.setUniform("materialDiffuseTexture", 0);
    shaderProgram.setUniform("materialSpecularTexture", 1);
    ...
}
ShaderProgram.unbind();

Texture.setActiveTextureUnit(0);
Texture.bind(texture);

Texture.setActiveTextureUnit(1);
Texture.bind(textureSpecular);
```

The relevant part of the `render()` method looks like the following:

```
ShaderProgram.bind(shaderProgram);
{
    //set other uniforms as projectionMatrix, viewMatrix, etc.
    ...

    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
ShaderProgram.unbind();
```

`texture`, `textureSpecular`, `shaderProgram` and `vaoID` are global variables.
The uniforms declared in the fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D materialDiffuseTexture;
uniform sampler2D materialSpecularTexture;
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my god, I feel so stupid right now. The problem was that I was using the `setUniform(String, float...)` method of my `ShaderProgram` class which called `glUniform1f(int, float)`.

But since the `sampler2D` uniform holds an integer I have to use `glUniform1i(int, int)` to assign the texture unit. Now it works!

Comment: It happens to us all. You might want to check out the Youtube Channel "ThinMatrix" who uploaded a tutorial on exactly this subject just 2 days ago.